# Who held the land (and from whom) around Pilleth, Wales at the time of the Battle of Brynglas 1402?

Tags: middle-ages, wales, mortimer, marches, glyndwr

This settlement in the Marches was the site of a battle in which Owain Glyndwr was the victor. There is a small church and a holy well that was a focus for pilgrims. I need background information about who lived nearby. Answers might be that there was a monastery which held the land, there was a manor house nearby held from a Marcher lord (Mortimer?). I have looked at the Mortimer Society and contacted local history societies without any result as yet. (I'm a writer planning a children's story and I can make up what is *not* known but I want to find out what *is* known first!) Even information on what is *likely* to have been the situation would help.

Comment: Mortimer seems like a good bet. Ralph of Mortimer was tenant-in-chief at Pilleth during the time of the Domesday Book and the Mortimer family retains its holdings in the area. Edmund Mortimer was captured in the very battle (which I assume is why you thought of them to begin with?)

Comment: Thank you. I had assumed that would be the case as he had a seat (if that's the right word) at Wigmore nearby. So what would have been the likely situation on the ground? Small farm(s) held from Mortimer, a manor house held from Mortimer with villeins working strips? Would there have been a priest at the church or was it run by monks from nearby? Where if so – the nearest I can find is Cwmhir about 16 miles away (I've contacted the  present vicar at Pilleth – nothing as yet). If it is all “not known” I can make it up! Otherwise I want to get it right.